# decode json response with nested arrays and loop into a table php

Tags: php, json

I want to loop through a json response by decoding and looping then present it on a table or at least have them in a variable .

my response : `$jdata=json_encode($response); Response: {"statuscode":"00","data":{"data":{"totalTransactionCount":9,"totalAmount":90000,"paymentDetails":[{"amount":"10000","lastStatusUpdateTime":"2021-07-24 05:51:59","status":"Pending Credit","statuscode":"072","RRR":"240008233690","transactionRef":"8233690"},{"amount":"10000","lastStatusUpdateTime":"2021-07-24 05:51:59","status":"Pending Credit","statuscode":"072","RRR":"320008233689","transactionRef":"8233689"},{"amount":"10000","lastStatusUpdateTime":"2021-07-24 06:06:59","status":"Pending Credit","statuscode":"072","RRR":"290008233697","transactionRef":"8233697"},{"amount":"10000","lastStatusUpdateTime":"2021-07-24 06:06:59","status":"Pending Credit","statuscode":"072","RRR":"270008233696","transactionRef":"8233696"},{"amount":"10000","lastStatusUpdateTime":"2021-07-24 05:51:59","status":"Pending Credit","statuscode":"072","RRR":"280008233687","transactionRef":"8233687"},{"amount":"10000","lastStatusUpdateTime":"2021-07-24 06:21:59","status":"Pending Credit","statuscode":"072","RRR":"190008233701","transactionRef":"8233701"},{"amount":"10000","lastStatusUpdateTime":"2021-07-24 06:06:59","status":"Pending Credit","statuscode":"072","RRR":"250008233695","transactionRef":"8233695"},{"amount":"10000","lastStatusUpdateTime":"2021-07-24 05:51:59","status":"Pending Credit","statuscode":"072","RRR":"300008233688","transactionRef":"8233688"},{"amount":"10000","lastStatusUpdateTime":"2021-07-24 05:36:59","status":"Pending Credit","statuscode":"072","RRR":"240008233685","transactionRef":"8233685"}]}},"requestId":"1627071656338","mandateId":"220008233651","status":"RECORD FOUND"}`  
// decode Json  to array

```
 $dresponse= (json_decode($jdata , true));
```

$dresponse["statuscode"]' // This works well but i cant get
$dresponse["data] to work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing inverted comma after data

Try
$dresponse[“data”]